# Connection between mmap offset and vma_area_struct vm_pgoff field

Tags: linux-kernel, mmap

What is the connection between the two fields?
I'm implementing my driver's mmap function. Is it true to assume that the 2 fields are equal, these are the original argument passed in the mmap call and the vm_pgoff I get as a field of vm_area_struct I get as an argument?

Comment: The `mmap` function uses an offset specified in bytes. `vm_pgoff` is an offset specified in pages. So the `mmap` offset is equivalent to `vm_pgoff * PAGE_SIZE`.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a reference which backs up this answer?

Comment: One reference is the comment for the `vm_pgoff` member of `struct vm_area_struct`. Depending on the version of your kernel sources, this is defined in `include/linux/mm.h` (before kernel version 2.6.24), or in `include/linux/mm_types.h` (since kernel version 2.6.24).